# JMeter is not showing any results when running a test plan

Tags: apache, jmeter

I tried to run a test plan in Jmeter but no results are displayed when I try to see the result as "view results as tree"

Whenever I run the test, the response I got on error log is shown in screenshot.

Anyone who have idea about this? please share it. It would be helpful.

[image: Results of test plan]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any Sampler, which means you don't submit anything.

Keystore configuration and HTTP Request defaults are just Configuration Elements.

Also `View Results in Table` is just a Listener that doesn't submit anything.

The listener defined to listen to Samplers as HTTP Request.

To get rows in listener you need to add, for example, Sampler-> HTTP Request which will display later request/response in listener after you run the test plan

See [JMeter's listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html)

> A listener is a component that shows the results of the samples

Comment: can u please explain this briefly

Comment: The listener is listening to Sampler as HTTP Request. you need to add for example Sampler-> HTTP Request which will display later in listener